# ActiveRecord .select(): Possible to clear old selects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to clear old selects in a .select("table.col1, ...") statement?

Background:

I have a scope that requests accessible items for a given user id (simplified)

```
    scope :accessible, lambda { |user_id|
  joins(:users).select("items.*")
    .where("items_users.user_id = ?) OR items.created_by = ?", user_id, user_id)
}
```

Then for example in the index action i only need the item id and title, so i would do this:

```
@items = Item.accessible(@auth.id).select("polls.id, polls.title")
```

However, this will select the columns "items.*, items.id, items.title". I'd like to avoid removing the select from the scope, since then i'd have to add a select("items.*") everywhere else. Am I right to assume that there is no way to do this, and i either live with fetching too many fields or have to use multiple scopes?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Fortunately you're wrong :D, you can use the `#except` method to remove some parts of the query made by the relation, so if you want to remove the SELECT part just do :

```
@items = Item.accessible(@auth.id).except(:select).select("polls.id, polls.title")
```

Comment: This is super helpful to know about. It seems to me that whenever you apply a `#select` clause that contains an AS alias (like `User.select("'a' AS abacus")...`, you always need to `except(:select)` before calling `#count`. Do you know of any case where this isn't true, and if not, any idea why `#count` doesn't automatically apply `except(:select)` for you? I'm working with some thorny geolocation filtering situations that are making this into a constant issue for me.

Answer (score 13):

## reselect (Rails 6+)

Rails 6 introduced a new method called [`reselect`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/reselect), which does exactly what you need, it replaces previously set `select` statement.

So now, your query can be written even shorter:

```
@items = Item.accessible(@auth.id).reselect("polls.id, polls.title")
```